Gmail API history().list() returns only history id?
I'm using Subscription listen script like this, but even though i sent new email for inbox every time it sends only,
{'historyId': 123456 },
i tried every possible changes i can think of regenerate access tokens, Purge Pub Sub messages still no luck, what i am missing here.
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from src.app.db import get_access_token
# from src.app.email_processor import get_message_from_historyid

config = dotenv_values(".env")

def callback(message):
    try:
        data_str = message.data.decode('utf-8')
        data = json.loads(data_str)
        history_id = data.get('historyId')
        print(data)
        get_message_from_historyid(email_id=data.get('emailAddress'), history_id=data.get('historyId'))
        
    except json.JSONDecodeError as json_err:
        print(f'Error decoding JSON: {json_err}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error processing message: {e}')
    finally:
        message.ack()

def create_gmail_service(email_id):
    token_data = get_access_token(email=email_id)
    credentials = Credentials(token=token_data['access_token'], refresh_token=token_data['refresh_token'], token_uri=token_data['token_uri'], client_id=token_data['client_id'], client_secret=token_data['client_secret'],)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)  
    profile = service.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()
    current_history_id = profile.get('historyId')
    print(f"Current history ID: {current_history_id}")
    return service

def get_message_from_historyid(email_id, history_id):
    
    print("\n",email_id, history_id,"\n")
    service = create_gmail_service(email_id)
    response = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    
    changes = service.users().history().list(userId=email_id, startHistoryId=history_id).execute()
    print("changes :: ", changes,"\n")
    
    
def listen_to_pubsub():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('./src/service_account_credentials.json')
    project_id = config["PROJECT_ID"]
    subsription_name = config["SUBSCRIPTION_NAME"]
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project=project_id, subscription=subsription_name)
   
    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print(f'Listening for messages on {subscription_path}')
    
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listen_to_pubsub()


Here there is a good explanation about what is happening

Here there is a good explanation about what is happening
